# Wildcard date format not resolved in Word

Tags: date, ms-word, wildcard

In this loop (iii = 12 to 1 step -1), the .text wildcard doesn't find any dates at all:

```
With Selection.FInd
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = WdFindStop
    .text= "([0-9]{1,2}] " & Mon_th(iii) & ([0-9]{4}])"
    .Execute
End With
```

But in this loop, it does:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
With.Find
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = WdFindStop
  .text= "([0-9]{1,2}] " & Mon_th(iii) & ([0-9]{4}])"
End With
```

I think I need to use the first version because I want to insert a comment every time a date is found, but can't figure out why it works with one but not the other.

All help appreciated, thanks.

Also, why does .text have an initial cap when I input it but changes to lower case immediately after?

Comment: You need to add .MatchWildcards=True.   In the example above you have used two different find object, one associated with a selection range and one associated with a Range range.  In the case of a Selection range you need to set the search parameters each time it is used.  For Range ranges, the parameters are 'sticky' and and remembered between uses.

Comment: Many thanks @freeflow. Now I can find all the dates in that wildcard format and add a comment each time. However... here's what I do in the .Execute (using the selection range version):
.Execute
    If .Found Then
        'Add comment code works OK, then...
        Selection.text = Format (.text, "mmmm d, yyyy")
    End If

The dates are changed, but not to the mmmm d,yyyy format - the text how looks like this: ([0-9]{1,2}) January ([0-9]{4}]), i.e. the original found format not the replacement one, and obviously only the month name is resolved. Again, this worked in the Range version.

Comment: @freeflow - looks like I fixed it now. Format line is now like this:
Format (Selection.text (...

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, do this without that loop. For example:

```
.Text = "<[0-9]{1,2} [JFMASOND][abceghilmnoprstuvy]{2,8} [12][0-9]{3}>"
```

or:

```
.Text = "<[0-9]{1,2} [JFMASOND][abceglnoprtuvy]{2} [12][0-9]{3}>"
```

If you need different comments, that can be achieved via a Select Case statement in the loop you'll already need for adding those. Thus:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[0-9]{1,2} [JFMASOND][abceglnoprtuvy]{2} [12][0-9]{3}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Select Case Split(.Text, " ")(1)
      Case "Jan": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Jan"
      Case "Feb": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Feb"
      Case "Mar": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Mar"
      Case "Apr": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Apr"
      Case "May": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for May"
      Case "Jun": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Jun"
      Case "Jul": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Jul"
      Case "Aug": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Aug"
      Case "Sep": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Sep"
      Case "Oct": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Oct"
      Case "Nov": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Nov"
      Case "Dec": .Comments.Add .Duplicate, "Comment for Dec"
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```